# Why doesn't the Nest Developer Tool Structure ID match the Structure ID returned via a get request?

Tags: nest-api

In the Nest Developer Tool (Chrome), I have Structure ID ***a*** while in the actual returned JSON blob I get a different Structure ID ***b***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the Chrome Extension which has been deprecated (as per the banner at the top of [this page](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/chrome-extension))

There is a new Chrome App, called the [Nest Home Simulator](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/home-simulator), that should solve your problem.

Comment: While the Nest Home Simulator is an improvement on interaction, it doesn't exactly solve the problem but rather removes the visibility of any ID's.

Comment: The ID that had formerly been displayed in the extension was the ID that the end user would be aware of (displayed in 1st party Nest apps). However the IDs returned via the API are only applicable for a given API client; this is to protect the end user's privacy (e.g. developers can't serve ads based on unique identifiers).

Comment: Ok I guess that is the answer I was looking for.